# Setting values with commas in namevaluecollection

Tags: c#, query-string, namevaluecollection

I am using the following code to access and manipulate query string

```
NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
qs.Set("OID", "5,6,7");
Response.Redirect( absolutepath + "?" + qs);
```

The problem is that query string ends up like this **"something.aspx?OID=5%2c6%2c7"** instead of **something.aspx?OID=5,6,7**

How can I format qs to get commas instead of %2c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(qs);`

Comment: I was trying with HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs) during the entire time.